# Question on possible Bilinearity of the Action of a Linear Functional on a Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, power-series, linear-transformations

I have been self studying the classical Umbral Calculus and have been reading works and papers from Rota and Roman on the material and I have a question regarding the following.  The text uses
$$\langle L \mid p(x) \rangle$$
to denote the action of a linear functional $L$ on a polynomial $p(x)$.  $P*$ denotes the vector space of all linear functionals on $P$, the space of polynomials.  Vector space operations on $P*$ are
$$\langle L+M \mid p(x) \rangle=\langle L \mid p(x) \rangle+\langle M \mid p(x) \rangle$$
$$\langle cL \mid p(x) \rangle=c\langle L \mid p(x) \rangle$$
Now, $F$ is the algebra of formal power series in $t$ over $\mathbb{C}$.  The formal power series 
$$f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!}t^k$$
defines a linear functional on $P$ by setting
$$\langle f(t)\mid x^n\rangle=a_n$$
for all $n\ge 0$.  As a consequence,
$$\langle t^k\mid x^n \rangle = n!\delta_{n,k}$$
Finally we know that since if
$$f_L(t)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\langle L\mid x^k\rangle}{k!}t^k$$
then it is easy to show that $L=f_L(t)$ and using the previous vector space definitions, the map $L\rightarrow f_L(t)$ is a vector space isomorphism from $P*$ to $F$.

Now, to my question, the evaluation functional is the power series $e^{yt}$, since
$$\langle e^{yt} \mid x^n \rangle=y^n$$

Then the text states

$$\langle e^{yt} \mid p(x)\rangle =p(y)$$

This is the first time in the text that shows the linearity argument for the action's argument.  From here, I can assume that if 
$p(x)=c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+c_1x+c_0$, then

$$\langle f(t) \mid p(x) \rangle =\langle f(t) \mid c_nx^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+c_1x+c_0\rangle$$
$$=\langle f(t) \mid c_nx^n \rangle+\langle f(t) \mid c_{n-1}x^{n-1} \rangle+...+\langle f(t) \mid c_1x \rangle+\langle f(t) \mid c_0 \rangle$$
$$=c_n\langle f(t) \mid x^n \rangle+c_{n-1}\langle f(t) \mid x^{n-1} \rangle+...+c_1\langle f(t) \mid x \rangle+c_0\langle f(t) \mid 1 \rangle$$

This linearity property was never explictly defined or shown, but I have to assume it is true because, by substituting in $f(t)=e^{yt}$, we do get $p(y)$ as our result.  This would seem to imply that this action is a bilinear functional and seems to mimic the bracket notation used by Halmos in Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces.  Is this an accurate assessment on my part?  And how would I have determined that this linearity existed for the argument $p(x)$ prior to the revelation by the evaluation functional $e^{yt}$?

Comment: You say that this notation defines the action of a linear functional on a polynomial. Linear functionals are linear by definition.

Comment: Okay.  That totally makes sense.  So $<f(t) | ap+bq>=a<f(t) | p> + b<f(t) | q>$ is simply true because $f(t)$ is a linear functional itself?

Comment: Yes, by definition.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.  It totally makes sense and i'm pretty sure I'm embarassed by the simplicity.  If you write up a brief explanation I would be happy to upvote and check.

Comment: Now, as the second question, does this make this make the action a bilinear functional?

Comment: There's nothing to check; once again, it's linear in the second variable by definition. And yes, once you also know that it's linear in the first variable, that's all it takes to make it bilinear.